# SQL Server keep crashing, cannot connect with SSMS, Agent not starting

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server, ssms

System
Windows Server 2003 x64
SQL Server 2005 x64

Problems:

1) Cannot connect via SSMS
- Tried both sa account and domain account (that is in sysadmin group)
- If I supplied the wrong password, then SQL Server respond I have invalid credential.
- If I supplied the correct password/use integrated security, I get the following error message: "A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

2) SQL Server Agent not starting
- Tried to start service with different accounts (with sysadmin privilege)
- No error from the UI
- SQLAGENT.OUT

```
2014-03-06 15:48:26 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover databases...
2014-03-06 15:48:36 - ! [165] ODBC Error: 0, Unspecified error occurred on SQL Server. Connection may have been terminated by the server. [SQLSTATE HY000] 
2014-03-06 15:48:36 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server '(local)'; SQLServerAgent cannot start
2014-03-06 15:48:36 - ! [165] ODBC Error: 0, Unspecified error occurred on SQL Server. Connection may have been terminated by the server. [SQLSTATE HY000] 
2014-03-06 15:48:36 - ! [382] Logon to server '(local)' failed (DisableAgentXPs)
2014-03-06 15:48:36 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

3) SQL Server (seems to be) crashing all the time.
- Service started without any error from the UI
- New error log / mini dump created every minute
- I have tried starting the service with a different account
- Log file shows:

```
2014-03-02 20:11:15.92 Server Error: 17310, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2014-03-02 20:11:15.92 Server A user request from the session with SPID 51 generated a fatal exception. SQL Server is terminating this session. Contact Product Support Services with the dump produced in the log directory.
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0052.txt
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 51 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * *******************************************************************************
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 *
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * 03/02/14 20:11:29 spid 51
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 *
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 *
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * Exception Address = 000000007814E250 Module(MSVCR80+000000000001E250)
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * Exception Code = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * Access Violation occurred reading address 000000180BAE6B40
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * Input Buffer 48 bytes -
2014-03-02 20:11:29.90 spid51 * exec sp_oledb_ro_usrname
```

I opened the crash dump and found the following

```
0:000> kc 51
Call Site
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject
kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx
sqlservr!CDmpDump::DumpInternal
sqlservr!CDmpDump::Dump
sqlservr!CImageHelper::DoMiniDump
sqlservr!ContextDumpNoStackOverflow
sqlservr!ContextDump
sqlservr!stackTraceExceptionFilter
sqlservr!ex_trans_cexcept
sqlservr!SOS_SEHTranslator
msvcr80!CallSETranslator
msvcr80!_CxxExceptionFilter
msvcr80!_CxxExceptionFilter
msvcr80!_InternalCxxFrameHandler
msvcr80!_CxxFrameHandler
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
msvcr80!memcpy
sqlservr!yyparse
sqlservr!sqlpars
sqlservr!CSQLSource::FParse
sqlservr!CSQLSource::FCompWrapper
sqlservr!CSQLSource::Transform
sqlservr!CSQLSource::Execute
sqlservr!process_request
sqlservr!process_commands
sqlservr!SOS_Task::Param::Execute
sqlservr!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask
sqlservr!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
sqlservr!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint
sqlservr!SystemThread::RunWorker
sqlservr!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker
sqlservr!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint
msvcr80!endthreadex
msvcr80!endthreadex
kernel32!BaseThreadStart
```

I think problem #1 and #2 is caused by #3. I have no idea what SPID51 is as I cannot even login with SSMS.

Fortunately we have a backup of the server and that was running fine.

What I have tried

- disabled all SQL services, except the main one
- -f -T3608
- start the SQL service with domain admin and local system
- start the server in minimal configuration mode
- disabled the network adapter just in case there is some unknown thing connecting to it
- disabled all other services on the server

none of the above fixed the issue

Comment: In the Services snap-in, open the properties for the SQL Server Service.  Stop the service.  In the Startup Parameters field, enter **-m**  and press Start.  This puts SQL in single user mode so that you should be able to connect directly to the database server without authenticating, but once you are in no other connections are aloud.  This could help you get in and isolate.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I edit the question but the formatting screwed up.  I tried to use -f to start in minimal configuration mode(which implies -m I believe). Doesn't work.

Comment: Are your SqlServer services configured to use users that are in the right SqlServerUserGroups and have the needed rights?

Comment: Yes, have used accounts that is both sysadmin and Domain Admin.

Comment: Have to reinstalled SQL server.